# Get value from radios as boolean instead of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like below to get the values of a series of radio that can either be True or False.

```
universalDetails = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'];
    $.each(universalDetails, function(idx, name) {
        universalDetails[idx] = {
            name: name,
            value: $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked', '#universalAttributes').val()
        };
    });
```

However, when I run this, the `value` comes back as a string ("True" or "False") versus a boolean. How can I adjust this to ensure I return a boolen and push into `universalDetails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check the current element

```
value: $('input[name=' + name + ']', '#universalAttributes').is(':checked')
```

OR `.prop()`

```
value: $('input[name=' + name + ']', '#universalAttributes').prop('checked')
```

OR Use the `length` property

```
value: $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked', '#universalAttributes').length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM property **`.checked`**, like this:

```js
universalDetails = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'];
$.each(universalDetails, function(idx, name) {
  universalDetails[idx] = {
    name: name,
    value: $('#universalAttributes input[name=' + name + ']')[0].checked
  };
});
console.log(universalDetails);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="universalAttributes">
  <input type="radio" name="thing1">Thing 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="thing2" checked="checked">Thing 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="thing3">Thing 3<br>
</div>
```

Comment: better use `.prop()` i.e. `$('#universalAttributes input[name=' + name + ']').prop('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

The values are always come from the html as strings. One thing which rest is no parse them to the `boolean`. Just compare your `value` with `true`. If they match (your string is also 'true') then you get `true` if not the other side, which is `false`.

`value: $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked', '#universalAttributes').val() == 'true'`

Code example

```js
let value = 'true';
let isTrue = value == 'true';
console.log(isTrue);

value = 'false';
isTrue = value == 'true';
console.log(isTrue);
```

With jQuery you can also check the state of the input using [**jQuery#is**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method

```
value: $('input[name=' + name + ']:checked', '#universalAttributes').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isTrueSet = (myValue === 'true');
```

**jquery**

```
$('input[name=' + name + ']').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop("checked")` instead of `.val()`